# yii removing sub folders from url string

Tags: yii

I'm trying to remove **/site/** and **/user/** from my url's on Yii. i tried adding this code

```
'contact' => array('site/contact', 'caseSensitive'=>false),
```

but i still can't get it to work. I'm trying to get all my static pages to look like `mydomain.com/about.html`

here are some of the url's i want to change

```
/site/page?view=about ==> mydomain.com/about.html
/site/contact.html ==> mydomain.com/contact.html
/user/login.html ==> mydomain.com/login.html
```

here is want i got so far

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
                'urlFormat'=>'path',
                'urlSuffix'=>'.html',
                'rules'=>array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    '<action:.*>'=>'site/<action>',
                    'user/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'user/<controller>/<action>',
                ),
                'showScriptName' => false,
            ),
```

this is my .htaccess

```
# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

# Unless an explicit file or directory exists, redirect all request to Yii entry script
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some rule staying before your rules for `main` and `user` is applied. The third one `'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'` always matches any route and preserves ids of controller and action in URL. Since first matched rule is applied all the following rules doesn't make sense.

You should move your rules to the top of `rules` array of `CUrlManager`. Supposing `main` and `user` are ids of your controllers they could look like this:

```
'rules' => array(
    '<view:(about)>' => 'site/page'
    '<action:(contact)>' => 'site/<action>',
    '<action:(login)>' => 'user/<action>',
    // the rest rules here
)
```

If you want to use `site/page` route not only for `about` view you should follow [parameterizing routes technique](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#parameterizing-routes). For example:

```
'<view:(about|guestbook|download)>' => 'site/page'
```

Using something like `'<view:\w+>' => 'site/page'` instead will also convert `/contact.html`  to `/site/page?view=contact` and `/login.html` to `/site/page?view=login`. As the result, all other rules that match these URLs will never be applied that's not acceptable for you.